# YouTubePlayerFragment: YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player

Tags: android, video, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to play YouTube videos inside a viewpager using YouTube API. My fragment consists of a FrameLayout in which I play the video. The video is loading but stop as soon as I play it.
The error log reads:

```
W/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. The YouTubePlayerView is obscured by android.widget.LinearLayout{ffe4270 V........ ........ 5425,0-6505,1437 #7f0e00cd app:id/root}. YouTubePlayerView is completely covered, with the distance in px between each edge of the obscuring view and the YouTubePlayerView being: left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 830..
W/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. The YouTubePlayerView is not contained inside its ancestor android.support.v4.view.ViewPager{d17b08c VFED..... ......I. 0,210-1080,1794 #7f0e0089 app:id/viewPager}. The distances between the ancestor's edges and that of the YouTubePlayerView is: left: 1085, top: 0, right: -1085, bottom: 830 (these should all be positive).
```

I cant figure out the problem as no view is obscuring the frame layout.
The Layout file is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- Youtube fragment -->
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible" />
<!--android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"-->
</linearLayout>
```

It still gives an eerror if i remove the outer layout and play only the framelayout.

Comment: How did you solve this. Please share your solution.

Answer (score -1):

In Android, when you use the YouTube API the video has to be in the top of the screen, neither you use an `YoutubePlayerFragment` nor `YoutubePlayerActivity`. If not the API raises an error like yours.

With this code i cannot be so much specific, but i guess that there is a layout covering your `YoutubePlayerFragment` and it is the cause because you see the error.

Hope it helps you,